Issue in Showing stock filter in layered Navigation Magento2
I followed below links to Display Stock filter in the layered navigation.
https://magecomp.com/blog/add-stock-filter-on-category-layered-navigation-magento-2/
Magento2: How do I add a filter for "is_in_stock" on category page layered navigation?
Created all the files as per the accepted answer.
Results are not showing properly. i,e layered navigation count, toolbar count and pagination is not matching properly.
Magento version : Magento cloud 2.4.5
MSI is enabled
Can someone look into this and update here the working solution.
Thanks in Advance!
